# each condition in the if() works independently, but when I add the digits to the if() to confirm the input is 15 digits, it breaks

Tags: c

each condition in the if() works independently, but when I add the "digits" to the if() to confirm the input is 15 digits, it breaks.

```
int main(void) {
  long x = get_long("card number?\n");
     
  //Luhn's algorithm for 15 digit CC
  //find even digits of CC
  int a = (((x/10) % 10)*2);
  int b = (((x/1000) % 10)*2);
  int c = (((x/100000) % 10)*2);
  int d = (((x/10000000) % 10)*2);
  int e = (((x/1000000000) % 10)*2);
  int f = (((x/100000000000) % 10)*2);
  int g = (((x/10000000000000) % 10)*2);
  //sum digits of products
  int h = ((a / 10) % 10) + (a % 10) + ((b / 10) % 10) + (b % 10) + ((c / 10) % 10) + (c % 10) + ((d / 10) % 10) + (d % 10) + ((e / 10) % 10) + (e % 10) + ((f / 10) % 10) + (f % 10) + ((g / 10) % 10) + (g % 10);
  //int i is the final sum for Luhn's algorithm  
  int i = h + (x % 10) + ((x/100) % 10) + ((x/10000) % 10) + ((x/1000000) % 10) + ((x/100000000) % 10) + ((x/10000000000) % 10) + ((x/1000000000000) % 10) + ((x/100000000000000) % 10);

  //digit counting loop
  int digits = 0;
  do {
      digits++;
      x /= 10;
  } while(x != 0);

  //american express if statement... [15 digits, starts with 3, sum of Luhn's algo ends in zero]     
  if (digits == 15 && (x / 100000000000000) % 10 == 3 && i % 10 == 0) {
    printf("American Express\n");
  } else {
    printf("invalid\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Consider starting with a loop which stores the digits in an array, while counting those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your code correctly, I think you're overwriting the original value of `x`. Specifically, this line: `x /= 10;` in the do-while loop re-assigns to x, but when you check the first digit here `(x / 100000000000000) % 10 == 3`, you're assuming that x is unchanged. The loop will exit with `x==0` but then `(x / 100000000000000) % 10 == 3` will always fail because the left hand side is always 0. To fix this, just store the card number in another variable before the while loop, like by inserting `long card_number = x;` above the do statement. Then in the `if` below, replace `x` with `card_number`

Comment: excellent point. sounds like that is the case.  Is there a way to run that do-while loop without overwriting x?

Comment: Updated answer with suggestion @DylanFlynn